# The bayes estimator of Bernoulli model with constant prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, loss-functions, risk

I'm currently reading "All of statistics" by Larry A. Wasserman.

In the chapter on statistical decision theory, we are given the following example:

> Consider the Bernoulli model with loss function $L(p,\hat{p})=\frac{(p-\hat{p})^2}{p(1-p)}$. It can be shown that for this loss function, $\hat{p}(X^n)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}$, is the Bayes estimator under the prior $f(p)=1$

I can't seem to prove to myself that indeed that is the Bayes estimator. All help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

[In my notation, $\theta=p$ and $k=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$.]

It is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference) that the posterior in this problem is
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi(\theta|y) &= & \frac{\theta ^{\alpha _{0}+k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{\beta _{0}+n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B}  \left( \alpha _{0}+k,\beta _{0}+n-k\right)}
\end{eqnarray}

The constant prior obtains for $\alpha_0=\beta_0=1$. We need to minimize the [posterior risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_estimator)
$$
\int\frac{(\theta - \hat{\theta})^2}{\theta(1 - \theta)}\frac{\theta ^{1+k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{1+n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left( 1+k,1+n-k\right)}d\theta=\int(\theta - \hat{\theta})^2\frac{\theta ^{k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left( 1+k,1+n-k\right)}d\theta\\
$$
Using properties of the Beta function $\mathcal{B}$, we have that
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathcal{B} \left( 1+k,1+n-k\right)&=&\mathcal{B} \left(k,1+n-k\right)\frac{k}{k+n-k+1}\\
&=&\mathcal{B} \left(k,1+n-k\right)\frac{k}{n+1}\\
&=&\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)\frac{n-k}{n-k+k}\frac{k}{n+1}\\
&=&\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)\frac{(n-k)k}{n(n+1)}\\
&\equiv&\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)m,
\end{eqnarray*}
where $m$ turns out to be irrelevant for minimization. Hence, we minimize
$$
P:=\int(\theta - \hat{\theta})^2\frac{\theta ^{k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)m}d\theta,$$
obtaining
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{\theta}}P=-2\int(\theta - \hat{\theta})\frac{\theta ^{k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)m}d\theta=0,$$
or
$$
\hat{\theta}\int\frac{\theta ^{k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)}d\theta=\int \theta\frac{\theta ^{k-1}\left( 1-\theta \right) ^{n-k-1}}{\mathcal{B} \left(k,n-k\right)}d\theta
$$
The left integral is 1, being a $Beta(k,n-k)$-density. The right integral equals $k/n$, being the mean of a $Beta(k,n-k)$(-posterior) density.